# Bash function to continue run if all files have size less than something

Tags: bash

I have little exposure to Bash scripting. I am trying to implement a bash function that runs some commands only if previous commands are successful. Particularly, here, I want to run the function if all the file sizes are less than a certain size.

## MWE

```sh
function myfunc() {
    files=`find . -type f -size +1M -print0 | xargs -0 du -h | sort -rh`
    echo "Files larger than 1MB ${files}"

    if len(files) > 0 then
        echo "At least one file has larger size, stopping the function"
    else
        echo "All files are less than size X, run other commands"
        echo "success"
    fi
}
```

How to make the function work?

Comment: Note that `files=$(...anything...)` is generally buggy. See [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: And the `function` keyword is syntax borrowed from legacy ksh - the POSIX sh standardized syntax just defines functions as `myfunc() {`. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of items in a variable, that variable should be an array.

In this case, it makes more sense to store an array with the list of raw files, and run it through `du` and `sort` only for output purposes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[0-2].*) echo "ERROR: bash 3.x needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac

myfunc() {
    # bash 3.0-compatible; readarray requires bash 4
    local file; local -a files=( )
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
      files+=( "$file" )
    done < <(find . -type f -size +1M -print0)

    echo "${#files[@]} found larger than 1MB" >&2

    if (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )); then
        # actually print a listing of our larger files
        printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" | xargs -0 du -h | sort -rh >&2
        echo "At least one file has larger size, stopping the function" >&2
    else
        echo "All files are less than size X, run other commands" >&2
        echo "success"
    fi
}

myfunc "$@"  # actually start our function
```

Note that output written for user consumption, rather than for other software to read, should be on stderr; hence the `>&2`s.

Comment: `ERROR: bash 4.x needed`

Comment: Means exactly what it says. What does `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` say you have?

Comment: Does is work for bash `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)`

Comment: Ahh. Okay, updated to work with the ancient version of bash that Apple ships. (If you install bash with Nix, Macports, Homebrew, etc., you'll get a much newer version -- it's on 5.x, but Apple refuses to ship anything since the switch to GPLv3 licensing in 4.0).

Comment: I am trying to write a simple git pull and push function, but it fails if some file sizes are larger and I am working in Macos with builtin bash 3.2.

Comment: _nod_. Edited version I expect to work in bash 3.2, though I don't have a copy around to test with handy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225325/discussion-between-milkyway001-and-charles-duffy).